# Problem with Authentication in sharepoint using active directory

Tags: sharepoint, authentication

I am currently using windows server 2008 machine. I have active directory and sharepoint setup on the machine. I have a user 'A' in the active directory and i have given the user read permissions to my site.

The problem i now face is that, if i log in as user 'A' the site simply shows "error:access denied". This problem goes away if i put 'A' as a site collection administrator, however that is not what i want. I just want 'A' to be a visitor that can browse the site.
I also tried granting 'read' permission to my site for 'A' but that still gives me the access denied message.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: are you using inheritted permissions from parent site? or you working on site collection

Comment: i'm sorry i am a little confused myself, but i was inheriting the permissions from the parent site before but now i have changed it to disinherit the permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats the cause of the problem your page library has got disintegrated from inherited permission from its parent site. you have to go to the page library settings and either add the user their as a viewer or start permission inheritance in the page library :)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. :)
i just checked the permission settings in the page library settings and user 'A' has Full Control Permissions. But i'm still getting the same message.

Comment: can you check the same for default.aspx page as well problem is due to breaking of the inherited permission settings.

Comment: i checked the settings for default.aspx and the user still has full control permissions. I checked on a couple of other pages as well, just to be sure, they too have the full control permissions.

Comment: are you working on a development environment or prod environment if it is dev kindly create a new site under same site collection with same site template and without inheriting permission. then add user A to the site and see how it behaves

Comment: Thank you a lot, i will try this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I am actually in development environment so i wasn't able to add to the current site collection, but i tried the permission for user A in a brand new web application and it works as it is supposed. Guess that means there's something wrong with the application that i have. Now at least i know where the problem is. Thank you so much for your advice, i am really grateful. :)